# Biblatex multible bibliographies using keywords not working

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm trying to print a sperate bibliography for references for figures but only one of the bibliographies prints at the end of the document.

Warnings in the document:

```
Keyword 'primary' not found on input line 8.
Empty bibliography on input line 8.
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document} 
Hello\cite{KandR} and Goodbye\cite{CUEDCplusplus}

\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title={Primary references}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary, title={Other references}]
\end{document}
```

bib.bib

```
@book{KandR,
   author  = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
   title  = {The C Programming Language Second Edition},
   publisher = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
   year = {1988}
}

@online{CUEDCplusplus,
   keyword={primary},
   author  = {Love, T.P.},
   title   = {CUED C++},
   url = {http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++.html},
   urlyear = {2010}
}
```

Screenshot of the result
[image: Only one bibliography prints]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That should be `keywords` (with s!) in the bib-file:

```
 keywords={primary}
```

Comment: Just in case it helps someone: I seem to have noticed that if you have several keywords and they are separated by a semicolon, or some by semicolon and some by commas, biblatex will ignore the `keywords` field and print the entry regardless of `\printbibliography`'s option. Mind those separators!

Comment: Can I add multiple `keywords`, as in `keywords={primary,secondary}` or `keywords={primary}, keywords={secondary}`...?